# Libevent HiRedis HTTP Server : Memory Leak in evhttp_send_reply

Tags: c, libevent, hiredis

I'm running the code located [here](https://gist.github.com/dspezia/2273908) which runs a simple HTTP Server using Libevent.

I ran a simple valgrind with the binary, and here's the [output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6205927), which shows a leak towards `evhttp_send_reply` & `evhttp_make_header` :: `L349` && `L350`

The leak shows a memory leak inside the libevent `evhttp_send_reply` & `evhttp_make_header` which surprises me, unless I've got something really wrong here.

can you see, what i've been doing wrong here.. ?

Comment: Please do not post links to the code, but include the relevant code in the question. So please edit the question to include the function, and please point out line 349 and 350.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the code is "only a sample", and is from another SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958589/async-redis-pooling-using-lib-event)